# Is this a Java Class Memory Leak?

Tags: java, memory-leaks

I have the following class with an object company. It holds a reference to the Company object only when Customer class goes out of scope. Do i keep in memory the whole Customer class or just the company object? Simple question.

```
public class Customer{

private Company co;

  void Customer(){}

}

}
```

Comment: If you don't have a reference to the `Customer` any more, it's eligible for garbage collection. Even if you have a reference to its `Company`, as long as the `Company` does have a reference to the `Customer`.

Comment: [When is an Object eligible for garbage collection in Java?](https://medium.com/@LazaroIbanez/when-is-an-object-eligible-for-garbage-collection-in-java-e0e43ed068a0) - Based on my (limited) understanding of the garbage collection process (and it's been a few years since I refreshed it).  Once there is no direct reference to the object, it will become eligible for GC - this means that, if the reference of `co` doesn't point to some other "strongly" referenced instance, then it will also be eligible for GC

Comment: @khelwood i dont understand. If i have a strong reference to the Customer's company, then Customer class will be gb collectable, but the company object will not. Right?

Comment: @Nick If you have a reference to the `Company`, but not to the `Customer`, then the `Customer` is eligible for garbage collection, but the `Company` is not.